# how to keep javascript global variable when redirect to another page

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to keep my javascript global variables after redirected to anothor page(**in the same domain**)?

I know i can use html5 localStorage/sessionStorage or store it on the server session state(and pull it later) . but when using complex or more then a few global variable, i wonder if there another quick way to use...

for example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title> first page </title>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          var myGlobal="this is my global variable";
            ...
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        ...
       <a href="secondPage.htm" ..> to the second page</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

and in the secondPage.htm:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title> second page </title>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          alert(myGlobal);    //I want it to be :  "this is my global variable";
            ...
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how about sessionstorage, localstorage or cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to keep my javascript global variables after redirected to anothor page(in the same domain)?

No.

New page = new execution environment.

> I know i can use html5 localStorage/sessionStorage or store it on the server session state(and pull it later) . but when using complex or more then a few global variable, i wonder if there another quick way to use...

Those are pretty much the only options you have. Small amounts of data could be stored in cookies.